# Google App Engine Backend for Android Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Cant find the 'Generate App Engine Backend' option in the google plugin for eclipse.

Has this been removed?? I am using a windows machine for development (I had heard that there was some problem with this option a few months back - has this been resolved)?

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed for now. Not sure when or if it will come back.